# How to copy a substring inside brakets from a string and subsequently remove it?

Tags: ios, xcode

i am getting text like :-
 `1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 {This opening is called the Ruy Lopez.} 3... a6
4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Be7 6. Re1 b5 7. Bb3 d6 8. c3 O-O 9. h3 Nb8  10. d4 Nbd7
11. c4 c6 12. cxb5 axb5 13. Nc3 Bb7 14. Bg5 b4 15. Nb1 h6 16. Bh4 c5`

I need to remove {the comment inside the } but before that i need to copy it along with the index number of the move like with 3 or with Bb5.

inorder to remove the string i am using

```
- (NSString *)stringFilter:(NSString *)targetString {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: targetString];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"{" intoString:NULL] ; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"}" intoString:&text] ;

        targetString = [targetString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@}", text]
                                                           withString:@""];

    } 

    return targetString;

}
```

I am looking for how can i copy that string and store it in dictionary or array thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following category method to get the contents between '(' & ')'. You can adapt it easily...

EDIT: Full category for completeness

```
//  NSString+Parenthesis.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Parenthesis)

-(NSString*)contentsInParenthesis;

@end

//  NSString+Parenthesis.m
#import "NSString+Parenthesis.h"

@implementation NSString (Parenthesis)

-(NSString*)contentsInParenthesis {
    NSString *subString = nil;
    NSRange range1 = [self rangeOfString:@"("];
    NSRange range2 = [self rangeOfString:@")"];

    if ((range1.length == 1) && (range2.length == 1) && (range2.location > range1.location)) {
        NSRange range3;
        range3.location = range1.location+1;
        range3.length = (range2.location - range1.location)-1;

        subString = [self substringWithRange:range3];
    }

    return subString;
}

@end
```

Comment: No - rangeOfString is declared by NSString itself. I have edited my answer to give you the full category. See NSString documentation for rangeOfString etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html